# Autocomplete script in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Hi I am new to webpage development, verified all related questions in Stack over flow but still I cant get the solution.

I am trying to include Autocomplete function in a input box and its works fine if my `Layout = null;` in View file, where as if I used my existing view template `ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";` Autocomplete function is not working

View File:

```
@model IEnumerable<AspNetRoleBasedSecurity.Models.PostModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row search-row">
<input class="search ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" id="CityName" placeholder="What do you need help with?"/>
<a class="buttonsearch btn btn-info btn-lg" href="search-results.html">Search</a>
</div>
```

Script Used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#CityName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetRecord",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Title, value: item.Title };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ref

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

C#

```
 public JsonResult GetRecord(string prefix)
    {
        DataSet ds = PostRepo.GetName(prefix);
        List<search> searchlist = new List<search>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            searchlist.Add(new search
            {
               Title= dr["Title"].ToString(),
                Tags = dr["Tags"].ToString(),
                Id = dr["Id"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return Json(searchlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I cant understand why its not working if `ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";` No error message received but autocomplete feature not works.
Please help me in understanding the concept.

Comment: Is there a layout.cshtml in your solution? Only thing i can think of is when Layout is null, it uses what you have only. But when you remove it and add the viewbag it goes and retrieves the default layout that may have something in it preventing autocomplete from working correctly.

Comment: Yes @Joy I just want to use auto complete function in my master page, is there is any other way to achieve this

Comment: The layout likely has a javascript reference that is causing conflict . Is there a line like @Scripts.Render("~/js") in your layout?

Comment: @DvynResh  Check browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

May be Check Layout out page scripts that you have referred

and  don't add in child views any scripts because scripts may conflict with multiple versions

here is the working example [auto complete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)